# Show icon at screen edge when corresponding object is out of view frustum

Tags: opengl, frustum

If an object moves out of the view frustum of the camera, I want to display an icon on one of the edges of the screen to indicate the rough direction where it is.

Unfortunately I have not come up with an idea yet how to do this. Can you please point me into a direction? Is there a special name for this?

Comment: What have you tried? Frustum culling could be applied here, and when object is being culled then just point an icon to the direction of the object from the camera near field center point.

Comment: @Lasse The frustum culling is working, I am wondering how to get from two 3d points (camera center point and object coordinates) to a 2d coordinate on the edge of the screen space. Right now I am thinking: project the line between the two points onto the near plane and intersect with the four sides to find the point in screen space

Comment: No need to project a line, you could project a single point. Also, you can project it directly onto a plane which has the camera point in it and is orthogonal to the view line.